# Класс std::ifstream, метод получения имени файла

Tags: c++, файлы

Доброго времени суток. Покопал много страницы учебников/интернета, но так и ничего не нашёл. Иногда требуется получить имя файла, к которому привязан файловый поток. Неужели нет ни функций\ни методов чтобы такое провернуть?\n
Заранее спасибо. Пока что спасаюсь немного костыльно:

```
class File :public std::ifstream 
{
    std::string name;
public:
    File():name(""), std::ifstream(){}
    File(const char* n, ios_base::openmode m = ios_base::in | ios_base::out):name(n), std::ifstream(n, m){}
    std::string name_file()
    {
        return this->name;
    }
};
```

Comment: Вот тут - http://www.vsokovikov.narod.ru/New_MSDN_API/Menage_files/obtain_name.htm - пытаются получить имя файла в Windows из его хэндла. Так что даже в операционке это непросто.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пожалуй, лучшее, что вы можете сделать - самостоятельно хранить имя.

Поскольку в стандарте об этом ничего не сказано - как минимум вы не можете получить имя файла переносимо. Вряд ли его какая-то реализация вообще хранит.

Даже просто найти по дескриптору операционной системы имя файла - задача нетривиальная (и не уверен, что вообще везде разрешимая).

Кстати, представим себе символические линки (или hard линки) - и какое имя файла теоретически нужно возвращать? А файл к тому же - еще и не всегда именно дисковый файл - например, откройте в Windows `fstream` с именем `con` - вывод пойдет на консоль. Можно отправить на принтер или еще куда.

Как я понимаю, все эти соображения вкупе с тем, что вы-то знаете, что открывали - привели к тому, что ни в C, ни в C++ нет функций получения имени файла из файлового объекта/потока.

Comment: Большое спасибо за подробнейшее объяснение! Действительно, выходит лучшее, что можно сделать - это использовать Ваше первое предложение.

Comment: Да не за что. Если ответ устраивает - помечайте как принятый :)